# Show virtual field in rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, postgis, postgresql-9.2, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have been using the information here (http://ngauthier.com/2013/08/postgis-and-rails-a-simple-approach.html) so that the search results in my app can be shown based on proximity.

I am listing all tasks with their associated project information - *a project can have multiple tasks*.

I have the following AR query in my `Project` controller:

```
@results = Task.select('tasks.*') # .select('tasks.*') required for pg_search
               .joins(:project => :user)
               .includes(:project => :user)
               .merge(Project.enabled_only.filter_by_location(@geo).search(params[:q]))
               .order_results(sort)
```

In my `Project` model I have:

```
scope :distance_from, ->(latitude, longitude) {
  select(%{
    ST_Distance(
      ST_GeographyFromText(
        'SRID=4326;POINT(' || projects.longitude || ' ' || projects.latitude || ')'
      ),
      ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(%f %f)')
    ) AS distance
  } % [longitude, latitude])
}
scope :near, ->(latitude, longitude, distance_in_meters = 1000) {
  where(%{
    ST_DWithin(
      ST_GeographyFromText(
        'SRID=4326;POINT(' || projects.longitude || ' ' || projects.latitude || ')'
      ),
      ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(%f %f)'),
      %d
    )
  } % [longitude, latitude, distance_in_meters])
}

def self.filter_by_location(geo_location)
  scoped = self.all
  if geo_location.present?
    scoped = scoped.distance_from(geo_location[:lat], geo_location[:lng])
    scoped = scoped.near(geo_location[:lat], geo_location[:lng])
  end
  scoped
end
```

I then have the following in my `Task` model:

```
scope :distance_order, -> { order('distance') }

def self.order_results(sort)
  # order scopes are appended
  scoped = self.all.reorder('')
  # check sql for search and distance fields
  search_performed    = scoped.to_sql.downcase.include?(' pg_search_rank')
  distance_calculated = scoped.to_sql.downcase.include?(' distance')
  if sort == 'rel'
    # rel,dist
    scoped = scoped.search_rank_order if search_performed
    scoped = scoped.distance_order    if distance_calculated
  else
    # dist,rel
    scoped = scoped.distance_order    if distance_calculated
    scoped = scoped.search_rank_order if search_performed
  end
  scoped = scoped.name_order
  scoped
end
```

This works fine for my app to sort results by proximity.

Distance is one of the columns in the sql select produced by the AR query, along with `tasks.*` and distance is being used correctly to sort results but I'm not sure how to display the distance in my view.

If I do `<%= result.distance.to_s %>`, it says distance is an undefined method. I don't have any joy with `<%= result.project.distance.to_s %>` either. Whereas `<%= result.task_field %>` and `<%= result.project.project_field %>` work fine.

I haven't seen too much use of both `.joins()` and `.includes()` at the same time in the RoR world but it did allow me to reduce the number of db calls whilst still producing the correct sql select statement...in my case anyway - that's why they are both used.

Am I missing something?

Is it the complexity of my AR query causing it?

Am I missing something in my `Project` or `Task` model to allow the virtual/calculated distance field to be display-able?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complex structure was replaced by a database view.

More details of how to do this can be found at this tutorial (http://pivotallabs.com/database-views-performance-rails/) and in one of my other SO questions here ([Connecting database view with polymorphic model in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27829613/connecting-database-view-with-polymorphic-model-in-rails)).