# Connecting database view with polymorphic model in rails

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, view, has-many-through, polymorphic-associations

I have the following setup which allows a user to have multiple projects and each project can have multiple tasks. A user can favourite multiple projects.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
  has_many :tasks, :through => :projects
  has_many :favourites
  has_many :favourite_projects, :through =>  :favourites, :source => :favourable, :source_type => "Project"
  has_many :favourite_tasks, :through => :favourite_projects, :source => :tasks
  ...
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :tasks
  has_many :favourites, :as => :favourable
  ...
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  ...
end

class Favourite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :favourable, :polymorphic => true
  ...
end
```

This setup allows `@user.favourite_tasks` to list all the tasks for the projects that they have favourited.

Taking the suggestion from here (http://pivotallabs.com/database-views-performance-rails/) I am trying to replace the multi-level table joins with a database view where possible instead.

The view SQL is:

```
SELECT tasks.id AS task_id, ..., projects.id AS project_id, ... 
FROM tasks INNER JOIN projects ON projects.id = tasks.project_id
```

My new `ProjectTask` model is:

```
class ProjectTask < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'task_id'
end
```

I've updated my `User` model to include:

```
has_many :project_tasks
```

which works fine for `@user.project_tasks`.

However, I can't figure out what the `has_many/has_one/belongs_to` should be in the models for the favourites to work (connecting the favourites to the view rather than the projects table).

I'm aiming for `has _many :favourite_project_tasks, :through => :favourites....` so that I can use `@user.favourite_project_tasks` in my controller and attach any `ProjectTask` model scopes to it if need be.
I think the fact that the `ProjectTask` model has `task_id` as the primary key is causing issue with rails linking the tables/view and because using `:through` overrides any use of `:foreign_key` and `:primary_key` (according to http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many).

Hopefully someone can advise what I should be doing because I've tried loads of combinations of changes with no joy.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue seems to have been caused by the custom primary key.

By updating the `User` model with (I was already doing this when it was failing):

```
has_many :favourite_project_tasks, :through => :favourite_projects, :source => :project_tasks
```

to use the view and also changing the view to use:

```
SELECT tasks.id AS id, ...
```

rather than:

```
SELECT tasks.id AS task_id, ...
```

and changing the `ProjectTask` view model to use:

```
self.primary_key = :id
```

it now works.